# ScopedTypeVariables between a type class and its instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

The [Haskell wiki on ScopedTypeVariables](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables) does not describe how the scope of a type variable is handled between a type class and its instance.

The following compiles

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
class A a where
  f :: forall b. a -> b -> (a,b)

instance A Int where
  f a b = (idb a, ida b)
    where idb :: b -> b
          idb = id
          ida :: a -> a
          ida = id
```

while the following does not (as expected: `Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘b’`)

```
g :: forall a b. a -> b -> (a,b)
g a b = (idb a, b)
  where idb :: b -> b
        idb = id
```

Since the wiki is silent, how was ScopedTypeVariables supposed to work with type classes?  Is this a bug, a misfeature, or by design? The wiki mentions some work-arounds that are Haskell98 and they seem to be compatible with using type classes (and thus superior).

EDIT:

As mentioned in a comment, `InstanceSigs` makes it possible to re-introduce the signature from the class and thus bring the type variables into scope.  But this seems very awkward compared to the Haskell98 alternative:

```
data D
instance A D where
  f a b = (idb a, b)
    where idb x = asTypeOf b x  -- gives the correct error message

{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
data E
instance A E where
  -- Complicated way to bring the class signature into scope..?
  f :: forall b. E -> b -> (E, b)
  f a b = (idb a, b)
    where idb :: b -> b
          idb = id
```

Doesn't it make more sense that the scope from the class declaration is re-used in the instance declaration to make ScopedTypeVariables work nicely with type classes?

Comment: I don't think the scoped type variable in the class of the first example has any bearing on the type signatures in the instance. If we turn on `InstanceSigs` and explicitly give `f :: forall b. Int -> b -> (Int, b)` in the instance, the code fails to compile.

Comment: Right, so when using `InstanceSigs` I would have to repeat the signature.  However, if I wrote `idb x = asTypeOf b x` which is the Haskell98 "workaround", I think I would get the compile error.

Comment: I don't think it's bringing them into scope. It looks to me like scoped type variables defined in the type signatures of a type class definition have no effect on anything. It seems to me like it would be very unintuitive otherwise, actually. If you are writing an instance for a type class you didn't make, it would be very easy to accidentally use a scoped type variable without knowing it, causing some strange looking errors.

Comment: @DavidYoung That's a fair point, but isn't this partly avoided by requiring `forall` to explicitly bring them into scope?

Answer (score 2):

In the instance definition you're not using scoped type variables. There you just provide annotations for `idb` and `ida` in the `where` block, and both are generalized to the same type, namely `forall a. a -> a` (modulo renaming of type variables), so they both work on any type.

Also, in the instance definition you have `A Int`, so there isn't any variable you could refer to.

Generally, type variables in an instance head are visible by default in the instance implementation if we have `ScopedTypeVariables`, and otherwise not visible. Also, note that when visible they can be shadowed by other scoped type variables (like any other scoped type var).

Examples:

```
class A a where
  f :: a -> b -> (a,b)

instance A a where
  f x y = (x :: a, y) -- an error without ScopedTypeVariables, fine with it.

instance A a where
  f x y = (x , y) where
    foo :: forall a. a -> a 
    foo _ = x -- an error, because we shadowed the instance "a" with the forall "a"
```